# firebase functions (emulator) + axios behaves differently on Windows and Mac

Tags: node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When I run a firebase functions locally on emulator, it works expectedly on Windows, but the same code doesn't work on Mac environment(I tried on two Mac: M1 and Intel, and neither doesn't work).

What I want to do is axios.post() to a specific API endpoint with:

1. query strings as authorization keys
2. accessing through squid proxy(SSL enabled) to make source IP address fixed

My firebase functions code here:

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions'
import https from 'https'
import axios from 'axios'
import {createHash} from 'crypto'

export default functions.region('asia-northeast1').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const sharedKey = "abcdefghijklmn"
  const randomKey = "opqrstuvwxyz"
  const sha256Hex = createHash("sha256").update(sharedKey+randomKey).digest("hex")
  const base64Encoded = Buffer.from(sha256Hex).toString('base64')

  await axios.post(
    `https://my.target.api.com`,
    {},
    {
      params: {
        auth_cd: base64Encoded,
        auth_key: randomKey,
        companyId: "myCompany"
      },
  // Below is just to avoid axios's error "Hostname/IP does not match certificate's
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      }), 
      proxy: {
        protocol: "https",
        host: "my.squid.proxy.com",
        port: 8080,
        auth: {
          username: "username",
          password: "password"
        }
      }
    }
  )
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

  res.status(200).end()
})
```

And this gives me an error "ERROR_LOGIN_AUTH_FAILED" on Mac, which is reproducible on Windows too in condition that one or more of the three params (auth_cd/auth_key/companyId) are wrong.

Also, I made development environment same both on Mac and Windows:

- Node.js: 14.19.3 (actually, here is another problem that if it's v16, the code above doesn't work on Windows too...)
- Java(firebase-functions uses): 11.0.16
- all the npm packages versions
- axios/firebase-functions/firebase-tools are the latest
- The other codes are the same too (cloned freshly from remote git repo)

I suspect this must be triggered some sort of difference on internal handling (like char code?) in axios, but no clues in my hand...

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're having a specific, reproducible problem with the emulator, it's better to post that as an issue to GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson
Thank you, I just posted issue on GitHub too.